# Create logs for each entry

Tags: excel, vba

I have only one cell (say A2) in Sheet1 to update and each time I update only A2 in Sheet1 I want a log of each entry seperately with date and time on another sheet2 row by row.

For example I firstly added Apple in A2 of Sheet1 and that should entry in Sheet2 as Apple in one column and Date and Time in another column 01/01/2019 10:00 AM.  Next time I again updated A2 from Apple to Mango then Sheet2 should reflect both Apple and Mango with different time stamp.

Hope the question is clear.  Kindly help me.

Comment: Sounds like you want to turn on *change tracking*?

Comment: Yes Mathieu kinda version controlling

Answer (score 1):

I would start with this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel

Then in that sub, find the next blank cell in your log and update that value to:

```
Now() & " Updated to: " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inputbox:

```
Sub updateA2()

    Dim oldValue As String
    Dim newValue As String
    Dim OpenCell As Range

    oldValue = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2").Value

    newValue = InputBox(Prompt:="Type a new value for A2.")

    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2").Value = newValue

    Set OpenCell = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlDown)

    'Make sure you have row headings and one row of data alread entered or this will go too far down
    OpenCell.Value = oldValue
    OpenCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = newValue
    OpenCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Now()
    OpenCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Environ("Username")


End Sub
```